# How do I select XElements by their XText Value?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<root>
 <descriptor>
  <content name="test">
   <foo>
     <bar>someValue</bar>
   </foo>
 </content>
</descriptor>
</root>
```

Given this simple example XML how can I select all of the "descriptor" elements if the attribute is not null and it contains a child "foo" with a value equal to "someValue"?

```
var elements = this.Descendants("descriptor")
              .Where(d => d.Element("content").Attribute("name") != null)
              .Where(d => d.Element("bar").Value == "someValue");
```

I would like the result to be a collection of "descriptors".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
var elements = this.Descendants("descriptor")
                   .Where(d => d.Element("content").Attribute("name") != null &&
                               d.Descendants("foo").Any(x => (string) x.Element("bar") == "someValue")))
                   .ToList();
```